# Google map with multiple markers and numbers and infowindow

Tags: google-maps

I want to display a map with multiple markers and it should display numbers in the marker and also an infowindow with info from the array.

It shows all the markers but with the number 5 in all of them and it is displaying the "Maroubra Beach" in the info window on all.
The info window itself, works as it should, that is that it opens on every marker as it should, but is displaying the wrong text!
Im not sure what Im doing wrong with the counter!? Since it is displaying 5 in all markers.

```
     var geocoder;
    var map;


    function initializemulti() {
//this is the geolocationmarker-compiled.js file

    (function() {var c=null,e;
    function f(b,a,d){var i={clickable:!1,cursor:"pointer",draggable:!1,flat:!0,icon:new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GeolocationMarker/images/gpsloc.png",new google.maps.Size(15,15),new google.maps.Point(0,0),new google.maps.Point(7,7)),optimized:!1,position:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),title:"Current location",zIndex:2};a&&(i=g(i,a));a={clickable:!1,radius:0,strokeColor:"1bb6ff",strokeOpacity:0.4,fillColor:"61a0bf",fillOpacity:0.4,strokeWeight:1,
    zIndex:1};d&&(a=g(a,d));this.a=new google.maps.Marker(i);this.b=new google.maps.Circle(a);this.b.bindTo("center",this.a,"position");this.b.bindTo("map",this.a);b&&this.e(b)}e=f.prototype;e.c=c;e.a=c;e.b=c;e.g=function(){return this.c};e.h=function(){return this.c?this.a.getPosition():c};e.f=function(){return this.c?this.b.getBounds():c};e.i=function(){return this.c?this.b.getRadius():c};e.d=-1;
    e.e=function(b){if(this.c=b){var a=this,b={enableHighAccuracy:!0,maximumAge:1E3};navigator.geolocation&&(this.d=navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(d){var b=new google.maps.LatLng(d.coords.latitude,d.coords.longitude);a.b.setRadius(d.coords.accuracy);if(!a.a.getMap()||!b.equals(a.a.getPosition()))a.a.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(d.coords.latitude,d.coords.longitude)),a.a.setPosition(b),a.a.getMap()||a.a.setMap(a.c),google.maps.event.trigger(a,"position_changed",new h(b,a.b.getBounds(),
    d.coords.accuracy))},function(b){google.maps.event.trigger(a,"geolocation_error",b)},b))}else navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.d),this.d=-1,this.a.setMap(b)};e.k=function(b){this.a.setOptions(g({},b))};e.j=function(b){this.b.setOptions(g({},b))};function g(b,a){for(var d in a)j[d]||(b[d]=a[d]);return b}var j={map:!0,position:!0,radius:!0};function h(b,a,d){b&&(this.position=b);a&&(this.bounds=a);d&&(this.accuracy=d)}h.prototype.position=c;h.prototype.bounds=c;h.prototype.accuracy=c;f.prototype.getAccuracy=f.prototype.i;f.prototype.getBounds=f.prototype.f;f.prototype.getMap=f.prototype.g;f.prototype.getPosition=f.prototype.h;f.prototype.setCircleOptions=f.prototype.j;f.prototype.setMap=f.prototype.e;f.prototype.setMarkerOptions=f.prototype.k;window.GeolocationMarker=f;})()


     //alert("init");
    var locations = [
          ['Big Boys Grill & Bar', '<br />Kungsgatan 28, Varberg'],
          ['Black Pearl Varberg', '<br />Kungsgatan 13, Varberg'],
          ['Bruket', '<br />Birger Svenssons väg 16 E, Varberg'],
          ['Comwell Varbergs Kurort', '<br />Nils Kreugers väg 5, Varberg']
        ];

        var mapen = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvasmulti'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.111488,12.246623),
          //center: undefined,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        //for displaying the current users location
         var GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
            GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
             // mapen.setCenter(this.getPosition());
             // mapen.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
              alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
            });

            GeoMarker.setMap(mapen);


        var  marker,i;
        var markers = [];

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var p = locations[i];

      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': locations[i][1]
      }, (function(i,p) {
        return function(results, status) {
          //alert(status);
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            //alert(results[0].geometry.location);
            mapen.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + ([i+1]) + '|FF776B|000000',
              map: mapen,
              title: p[2]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent(p[0] + p[1]);
              infowindow.open(mapen, this);
            });

            // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { infowindow.open(mapen, this);});
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
              infowindow.close();
            });

          } else {
            alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
          }
        };
      })(i,p));

    }

    }
```

Any input really appreciated, thanks!

Ok so this works, except for that the blue dots is not showing? The circle around the users location i showing, but not the blue dot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: It is really a duplicate, just not an exact duplicate. The concept of the fix is the same, just you are using the geocoder to get the positions of your markers, which requires a different function closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anonymous function closure (doesn't *have* to be anonymous, named functions work as well) to keep the information associated with the geocode request (for use in the callback) and in the infowindow click event handler (for use when the marker is clicked).

```js
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', '850 Bay st 04 Toronto, Ont'],
  ['Coogee Beach', '932 Bay Street, Toronto, ON M5S 1B1'],
  ['Cronulla Beach', '61 Town Centre Court, Toronto, ON M1P'],
  ['Manly Beach', '832 Bay Street, Toronto, ON M5S 1B1'],
  ['Maroubra Beach', '606 New Toronto Street, Toronto, ON M8V 2E8']
];

var mapen = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.253205, -80.480347),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var p = locations[i];

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': locations[i][1]
  }, (function(i,p) {
    return function(results, status) {
      //alert(status);
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        //alert(results[0].geometry.location);
        mapen.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + ([i]) + '|FF776B|000000',
          map: mapen,
          title: p[2]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(p[0]);
          infowindow.open(mapen, this);
        });

        // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { infowindow.open(mapen, this);});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
          infowindow.close();
        });

      } else {
        alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
      }
    };
  })(i,p));
}
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map_canvas {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot geocode zip, works great! Just one more question, if I want to display the name and a line break with the address underneath it in the info window, how do I do that?
I have infowindow.setContent(p[0] + p[1]);
And with this address ['Big Boys Grill & Bar', ' Kungsgatan 28, Varberg'],
it is displaying "Varberg" as well, how can I not show it ? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The info window content is HTML, use a `<br>` (or any other HTML formatting tags you want).

Comment: Ok it worked when I find the geolocationmarker-compiled.js file that had to be included. But it is not showing the blue dot?

Comment: I have updated my code with the one that I have wiring now, but still the blue dot is not showing? Any input on that? Thanks!

Comment: By the "blue dot", do you mean the `GeolocationMarker();`, that isn't part of my answer, as it wasn't related to your original question.  Leave that in your code as it was.

Comment: Yes, but I found out that it was the wrong address to the image itself! So it works.

Comment: geocodezip! Thanks for you help. As you seams to know you way around this I wonder if you could have at look at a new post about this - I have the over the query limit problem and I thought it was best to post a new question about that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364994/how-to-avoid-geocoderstatus-over-query-limit Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're loosing marker reference and only keeping the last one (note your array has 5 elements), to keep them, just create a markers[] array to store them:

```
var markers = [];
```

Then when marker is created add it to array

```
markers.push(marker);
```

Your code will be like this:

```
var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', '850 Bay st 04 Toronto, Ont'],
      ['Coogee Beach', '932 Bay Street, Toronto, ON M5S 1B1'],
      ['Cronulla Beach', '61 Town Centre Court, Toronto, ON M1P'],
      ['Manly Beach', '832 Bay Street, Toronto, ON M5S 1B1'],
      ['Maroubra Beach', '606 New Toronto Street, Toronto, ON M8V 2E8']
    ];

var mapen = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.253205,-80.480347),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var  marker,i;
var markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var p = locations[i];

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': locations[i][1]}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        mapen.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon:'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+ ([i]) +'|FF776B|000000',
        map: mapen,
        title: p[2]
     });


     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.setContent(p[0]);
         infowindow.open(mapen, this);
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { infowindow.close();});

     // insert created marker in the array
     markers.push(marker);

     }
     else
     {
         alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
     }
  }); 
}
```